# Toast "setGravity" doesn't work on fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, toast, android-toast

All the toasts I use in a fragment are shown in the same place. I tried to change the position using this code:

```kotlin
val t = Toast.makeText(
    context,
    "hello",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
)
t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
t.show()
```

but it doesn’t change anything at all. I’m not sure if I have to do anything else because this code is in a fragment, not in the main Activity. Thanks!

Comment: If you're running on and targeting Android 11 or above, that doesn't work anymore: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#text-toast-api-changes.

Comment: is it a snackbar a good alternative?

Comment: SnackBar is also stuck at the bottom of the screen. There's a hack to get it to appear at the top, but the show/hide animations will look terrible when it's in that position. You’ll need a third party library like this if you don’t want to have to build your own solution: https://www.github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar